# Devise translation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I have registration in devise, look like this:

```
<%= semantic_form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name) do |f| %>
<li id='errors'><%= devise_error_messages! %></li>
<span><%= f.label :email ,'Adres email' %></span>
                    <li><%= f.email_field :email %></li>

                    <span><%= f.label :password ,'Hasło' %></span>
                    <li><%= f.password_field :password %></li>
```

And i try to translate devise with I18n, but with no results. When i put wrong password i see :

```
Password należy uzupełnić
```

Second half of it is translated but word "password" is not. I try many things like:

```
 activerecord:
   attributes:
     user:
       password: SHIT
```

but it doesn't work. Also try put it in :

```
errors: &errors
    format: ! '%{attribute} %{message}'

    messages:
```

but still it doesnt work. Also try with

```
formtastic:
   user:
       password:
```

but nothing works. Where i can translate words like: password, email, password_confirmation and other value from form.

And this is an answer:

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    user:
      password: Hasło
      email: Adres email
      password_confirmation: Hasło
    profile:
      age: Wiek

 <<: *errors
```

Comment: dont undestand - how can i set devise_errors in view with labels

Comment: Sorry misunderstood. Ignore it.

Comment: Are you using the devise i18n files?

Comment: AFAIK if you've got `resource` in `form_for` then you should add attributes   for `resource` in locale, now you have `resource` in form and `user` in locale.

Comment: ok i got answer. Activerecord attributes for user and profile

Answer (score 4):

Simple check out the default en.yml translation file from devise to change the defaults:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml

Copy that file and create your own translations.. for example devise.de.yml, devise.es.yml and so on.. that should solve your problem.

If you´d like to translate your model attributes, it does not depend on devise. that´s normal rails stuff.. check out this link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html